# Merge replication non-convergence

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge, replication

Operating system on all servers: Windows Server 2008 R2.

Publisher: Sql Server 2008 R2 Standard

Distributor: SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard

Web Synchronization Agent: sqlce35.dll under IIS 7.5

Subscriber: Windows XP SP 3 or Windows 7 SP1
                   SQL CE Client 3.1

I have an issue where a merge replication stops updating subscriptions without knowing why.

Premises:

- 1 Publication
- 15 items filtered by hostname(). All set to download, None in bidirectional mode.
- 20 or 30 subscribers

You create a merge replication with several articles (15 tables) filtered by a HostName (). This replica push over 20 or 30 subscribers and the synchronization is done correctly. Data collection is done by request from the subscriber, it pull changes two or three times a day. And all the changes are received by the subscriber without any problem.

All this works fine until there comes a time, after a few days without problems the replica will no longer updating a few changes to the subscriber. We search on publicator and have the changes, check the subscriber and not have them. Returning to modify the changes in publicator, sometimes if they are updated in the subscriber and sometimes not.

The problem is that this replica is no longer reliable, we do not know that it is updated and what not.

Focusing on a single subscription-EVDBASD342232 '013243 ... 'and a single article' table1 'is not getting new data made the following verification steps

- Run "sp_showpendingchanges NULL, NULL, 'table1', 1" means the
  procedure returns me a series of rows that correspond to the data
  that should be replicated, I have found that the ID matches the
  subscription-EVDBASD342232 '013243 ... 'and the guid corresponds to
  the row on the 'table1' that should be replicated.
- We request subscription and we observe in the Replication Monitor to
  view subscription-EVDBASD342232 '013243 ... 'indicating 0 changes and
  everything is correct, shows no errors but will not say anything
  pending synchronization.

After analyzing all the data we do not understand is what is going wrong in the process.
Once a replica does not synchronize, the others do not either.

Please if anyone can help, thanks in advance.
If you need more clarification or details

Answer (score 0):

SQL CE has known issues with replication.
Most advice is to not use CE.

Try contacting Hilary Cotter - I think he has a blog and a twitter.

Twitter #SQLHELP is a great place to get an answer as soon as possible. Most of the SQL gurus are there to help you.